# How to take values of of scope in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following function written in swift:

```
func FFT_Analyzer (frequencies:[Double], magnitudes:[Double], sort_mag:[Double], harmonics:[Double]) -> (chatter_freq:Double,
    chatter_mag:Double) {


    //establish a counter to iterate through all the arrays: 
    var ffcounter = 0
    var temp_Bool = 0
    var chatter_freq:Double = 0
    var chatter_mag:Double = 0

    //establish a while loop that runs for the entirety of the frequency/FFT arrays:
    while  ffcounter < frequencies.count {

        //use y_descend, to go down the frequencies with descending magnitude
        var chatter_mag:Double = sort_mag[ffcounter]
        println("The chatter magnitude is: \(chatter_mag)")

        //determine the index of the frequency with highest amplitude
        var mag_index = find(magnitudes, chatter_mag)
        println("The chatter inded is: \(mag_index)")

        //using the index, find the corresponding frequency:
        var chatter_freq:Double = frequencies[mag_index!]
        println("The chatter frequency is: \(chatter_freq)")

        //use a FOR loop to check whether this frequency is a forced frequency/harmonic:
        for element in harmonics {
            if (((element-1) < chatter_freq) && (chatter_freq < (element+1))) {
                temp_Bool = 0
                break
            }

            else{
                temp_Bool = 1
                continue
            }
        }
        if temp_Bool == 0 {
            ffcounter = ffcounter + 1
            continue
        }
        else {
            println(chatter_freq)
            println(chatter_mag)
            break
        }

        //return (chatter_freq, chatter_mag)
    }
    println(ffcounter)
    println(temp_Bool)
    println(chatter_freq)
    println(chatter_mag)

    return (chatter_freq, chatter_mag)
}
```

I have defined  ffcounter, temp_Bool, chatter_freq, and chatter_mag BEFORE the while and for loops for the sake of having the variables in scope. However I run into the following isssue:

ffcounter and temp_Bool will be updated to their final values when my code is finished running ( 2 and 1 respectively), however, the values for chatter_freq and chatter_mag do not pass through the end of the function. In other words, chatter_freq and chatter_mag are updates inside the while loop, but I cannot pass these values outside of the while loop. As a result chatter_freq and chatter_mag are equal to their initial values: 0.0.

Does anyone know how I can take values out of the "scope" of the code block in which they are updated?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring *new* instances of those two variables within the loop even though you've declared them outside the loop previously.

Just change the ones inside the loop from:

```
var chatter_mag:Double = sort_mag[ffcounter]
var chatter_freq:Double = frequencies[mag_index!]
```

to:

```
chatter_mag = sort_mag[ffcounter]
chatter_freq = frequencies[mag_index!]
```